# How do I add all of the first 314159 digits of pi?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
sum=0
counter=0
x=0
req=requests.get("https://www.piday.org/million/")
soup=BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
tag=soup.find(id="million_pi").get_text()

# Calculate the sum of digits in the first million digits of pi
for digit in tag:
    if digit.isdigit():
        sum += int(digit)
        counter+=1
    if counter>314160:
        break
print(sum)
```

This is my code. I'm trying to scrape the digits from a website, and add them together. The problem is after the counter reaches 51198, it doesn't add anymore, and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

I tried breaking the range into segments and evaluating each individually, but it didn't work.

Comment: If you load the page you'll notice that it only loads new numbers once you scroll down. You'll have to look into [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or check out the developer tab to see how it loads.

Answer (score 1):

The data you see on the page is loaded with Javascript from different URL. Here is an example how you can load more pages and then add the numbers together:

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.piday.org/wp-json/millionpi/v1/million?action=example_ajax_request&page={page}"

final_number = []
for page in range(1, 3):             # <-- change number of pages here
    data = requests.get(url.format(page=page)).text
    final_number.append(data[1:-1])

print("".join(final_number))
```

Prints:

```
3.1415926535897932384  ...
```